# How to give App level access in Firebase Project

Tags: android, firebase

I've a Firebase project with two apps- One is for debug purpose and other is for Production.

Now, If I give access of project to other users they are able to see the debug and production apps data. But I want the access to be given on App basis.

Is it possible in Firebase project?

Comment: yes you can do that either by implementin gauthentication or by writing rules for access in the database.

Comment: writing rules for access, is the best way to go